# Writeback in tableau (getting error while implementing in greenplum db)

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I tried write back through Oracle DB, and its working like charm!! But my need is to do it through Greenplum Postgresql DB. When I am trying exactly same thing through postgre it shows an error..
[image]

Below is the function which I have used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_upd_user_comments(var_id_text IN VARCHAR)
  RETURNS varchar AS $$
  BEGIN       
   UPDATE xxxx.Main_Table_Comment
   SET comment = ('RTY')
   WHERE ID = 1;
   RETURN 'TRUE';
   EXCEPTION
        WHEN unique_violation THEN
     raise notice 'Error in Updating Records';
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In above function I have hard coded the value.

Answer (score 1):

I found your post on Tableau's site and the link you provided here: http://community.tableau.com/message/194207#194207

The general consensus is that this "feature" is a hack and shouldn't be done.  Use Tableau as a read-only reporting tool.  It seems you are wanting some type of user Form that will allow DML statements and then call a report.

Here is an example of what you are trying to do and it doesn't work:

```
    create table emp
    (empno int, 
     ename varchar,
     job varchar,
     mgr varchar,
     hiredate date,
     sal numeric,
     comm numeric,
     deptno int)
     distributed by (empno);

    create table tab_comment
     (val varchar) 
     distributed randomly;

    create or replace function fn_save_my_parameter(p_val varchar) returns varchar as
    $$
    insert into tab_comment select $1;
    select 'true'::varchar;
    $$
    language sql;

    insert into emp (empno, ename)
    select i, 'name_' || i from generate_series(1, 100) as i;
```

And when you try the SQL as it was done with the Oracle example, it doesn't work.

```
    select  empno, ename, job, 
            mgr, hiredate, sal,
            comm, deptno, val
    from emp cross join tab_comment
    where fn_save_my_parameter('some comment') = 'true';

    ERROR: function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement (functions.c:135)  (seg0 slice2 gpdbvm43.localdomain:50000 pid=1462) (cdbdisp.c:1326)
    SQL state: XX000
    Detail: SQL function "fn_save_my_parameter" during startup
```

That looks just like your error message.  This is not a supported feature of Functions in Greenplum.

Comment: Yes I know this is not a good practice, but I have a requirement to writeback in tableau. Requirement is to insert a comment in respect to the item id. So I created a table xxxx.Main_Table_Comment, added all Item IDs (from main table) and trying to update the comment column with respect to item ID. Later will join the comment and main table, and show it.

So I want whole process to be done in tableau in GP. I already tried doing this in Oracle, and its working fine. But in tableau it throws above error (screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Just got solved this issue...

In custom SQL there was slightly addition in query:

```
Select *
from xxxx.main_table
where ( SELECT fn_upd_user_comments (<Parameters.Param>))='TRUE'
```

Select was missing before the command.

This got solved my query...
Thanks all for your time.